# Bootstrap Nav link not opening or working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am having problems with the bootstrap nav. I am using this nav for mobile phones, otherwise it is not visible. Logo on the left works but the button on the right does not. I cannot find what is the problem. 
HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top mobile" role="navigation" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:white"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:white"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:white"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top" style="color:white"><img class="pull-left" style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;" src="theme/logo.png"></a>

            </div>

             <!--Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
            </div>
           <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
 </code>
```

And CSS:

```
<pre>@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic);
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
:link,:visited {text-decoration:none}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code {font-size:48px;font-weight:400; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0.5em;}
h2 { line-height: 1em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; }
ul,dl,dt,dd,ol,li,/*h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,*/pre,form,body,html,p,blockquote,fieldset,input {margin:0; padding:0}
h3, h4 { font-size:30px; line-height: 1em; margin-bottom:0.5em;}
a img,:link img,:visited img {border:none}
p {margin-bottom: 0.5em;}
hr { margin: 25px 0; height: 1px;
    background-color: #333333;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
     }

.strong { font-weight: bold; }


/** GLOBAL SETS **/
div { display: block; }
.clear {clear:both;}

.hidden {display:none;}

body {margin:0 0 50px 0;font-size:26px;color:#17331f;font-family:'PT Sans',lucida,tahoma, helvetica, verdana;background:#ffffff;text-align:left; }

a:link, a:visited {color: #253066; text-decoration:underline;}

a:hover, a:focus {text-decoration:none;}
#yhteysheader a:link, #yhteysheader a:visited {color: #ffffff; text-decoration:underline;}

#wrapper {position: fixed;top:185px;width:100%;margin:0 auto;display:block;height: 100%; overflow:auto;}

p, h1, h2 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  }
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  }

#header {top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
position: fixed; display:block;
z-index: 100;height:165px; text-align: left; background:#17331f; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #253066; margin:0; padding: 0;}
.contain { width: 1080px; margin: 0 auto;}
.sisalto { min-height: 600px; height: auto; margin-bottom: 35px; margin-top: 14px; /*background: url(images/rattitausta.png) top left no-repeat;*/ }

/*div.topfix { padding-top:105px; }
div.topfix_hist { padding-top:75px; }*/

div.left { float: left; height: 100%; margin: 10px; }
div.right { float: right; height: auto; }
.teksti { width: 760px; }
.tekstikapea { width: 500px; }
.tekstikeski { width: 630px; }
.kuvakeski { width: 375px; }
.kuva { width: 100%; }
.kuvalevea { width: 500px; }
.kuva img { width: 100%;  }
isokuva


#menu { display: block;position: relative;height: auto; margin-top: 70px; width: 680px; float: right;}
#menu ul#nav {display: block;position:relative;list-style:none; margin-bottom: 0;height:auto;height:0; padding:0; float: right;}

#menu #nav li {float:left;margin:0;font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;}

#menu #nav li a {display:block;line-height:20px;padding:10px 20px;}
#menu #nav li.firstli a { }

#menu #nav li a:link, #menu #nav li a:visited {color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;}

#menu #nav li a:hover, #menu #nav li a:focus {color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;}

#menu #nav li.current a  {border:1px solid #FFC4C4;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;}


h1#logo { position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 0; display: block; width: 400px; height: 132px; background: transparent url(logo.png); visibility: visible;  border: 0;overflow: hidden;  z-index: 999: text-align: left; float: left; clear: none !important; }
h1#logo a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0;
  height: 132px;
    height: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 132px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 400px;
  clear: none;
}
h1#slogan { color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; float: left; clear: right;padding-top:10px; margin-bottom: 0; display: block; }
#yhteysheader {
margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  color: #ffffff;
  }

#page-content {text-align: left; margin-top 35px; }





@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {

    #header {

        height: 160px;
    }
    #palvelut h2 {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    #yhteysheader {

        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .pored {

        padding-left: 10px !important;
    }

    .veliki {

        padding: 0px;

    }

    .veliki i {

    }

    #menu ul li {

        width: 20%;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .naslov{
        margin-top: 210px !important;
    }

     i {


        padding-left: 19px;
    }
  #menu #nav li a{
    padding: 0;
  }



 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {

  .slicica{
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }


 }


 @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {

    #header {
      display: none;
    }

    .mobile {
      visibility: visible !important;
      display: block !important;
      background-color: #17331F;
      color: white !important;

    }

    .mobile a {
      text-decoration:none;
    }

    #palvelut h2 {
        margin-top: 2px;
    }
    #wrapper{
      top: 60px !important;
    }

    #menu ul li {

        padding: 1px;
        margin: auto;
    }


    #menu ul li a {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #menu ul li a i {
        padding-left: 13px; 
    }

    h2 {

        font-size: 30px;
    }

    p {

        font-size: 17px;
    }

    .forma {
        font-size: 17px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }

    .mapa {
        height: 500px !important;
    }

    .veliki i {

        padding-left: 0px !important;
    }
    .dugme{

    }
    footer{
      bottom: 50px !important;
    }
    .video{
      width: 100% !important;
      left: 0% !important;
    }

 }



.video {
  width: 60%;
  left: 20%;
}




#content .page-text img {border:none;}

div#palvelut ul { /*list-style: none;*/ padding-left: 1em; }

div#footer { background: url(images/bisnesmuotoilulogo.png) bottom left no-repeat; padding-top:30px;margin-top:30px;border-top:1px dotted #ccc; height: 200px; }

.section {padding:30px 20px 20px 20px;text-align:left;}

.section p, .section ul, .section ol {line-height:20px;margin:0 0 20px 0;}

.section ul, .section ol {margin-left:20px;}

.section ul ul, .section ol ul, .section ul ol, .section ol ol {

  /*margin:0 0 0 20px;*/

}

.section h2 {color:#BA0000;font-size:22px;font-family:arial;line-height:22px;letter-spacing:-1px;margin:0 0 15px 0;padding:0;}

.section h3 {color:#BA0000;font-family:arial;font-size:19px;margin:0 0 10px 0;}

.section h4 {color:#BA0000;font-family:arial;font-size:15px;margin:0 0 10px 0;}

.section h5 {color:#BA0000;font-family:arial;font-size:13px;margin:0 0 10px 0;}

.section h6 {color:#BA0000;font-family:arial;font-size:10px;margin:0 0 10px 0;}



.section blockquote {

  margin:0 0 20px 20px;

  line-height: 19px;

  font-size:12px;

  color:#666;

  font-style:italic;

  border-left:2px solid #ccc;

  padding:0 0 0 15px;

  }

.section code {border:1px solid #ececec;padding:2px;font-family: Consolas, Monaco, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;font-size: 12px;background:#f9f9f9;color:#000;}

.section pre code {line-height:17px;padding:15px;border:1px solid #ececec;font-family: Consolas, Monaco, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;font-size: 12px;background:#f9f9f9;color:#000;margin-bottom:22px;display:block;}



.credits {font-size:11px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#666;padding-top:15px;margin-top:30px;border-top:1px dotted #ccc;}

.credits p {margin:0 0 0 0;line-height:16px;padding:5px 0 0 0;}

.credits a:link, .credits a:visited {color:#666;}

.credits a:hover {color:#333}

footer {
  overflow: hidden;
}</pre>
```

I would really appreciate the help in making this work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include the following:

> Before closing body tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> In between your head tags, but before your custom styling:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Great! It works. Thanks a lot :)